# app icon is not showing in app menu in android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-icons

When I run my app from android studio the app is installing but the icon is no showing in app menu. It only shows in home screen. I have not changed anything in manifiest. Everything was fine, suddenly this problem started. I am struggling with it for 3 hours. Its annoying. If you see these pictures you will understand.

[image]

[image]

See the Beat Box icon is missing from first picture. Why this is happening?

my manifiest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="prime.beatbox"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/download"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Player"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_player"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".EgineBackground"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".Statistics"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_statistics"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AlbumItems"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_album_items"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ArtistAlbum"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_artist_album"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AnimationTest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_animation_test"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DataBase"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_data_base"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EqualizerLocal"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_equalizer"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".EgineBackground$PreviousButtonListener"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".EgineBackground$NextButtonListener"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".EgineBackground$PlayButtonListener"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".EgineBackground$CancelButtonListener"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".NewAppWidget$NextButtonListenerNotification"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".NewAppWidget$PlayButtonListenerNotification"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".NewAppWidget$GoToApp"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".EgineBackground$CallDetector"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".Themes"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_themes" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".sleep"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sleep" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Favourite"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_favourite" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PhoneMemory"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_phone_memory" >
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".NewAppWidget" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/new_app_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MyFolders"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_folders" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CardMemory"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_card_memory" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PlayList"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_play_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PlaylistDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_playlist_details" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SongDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_details" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchBox"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_box"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchAlbum"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_album" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your manifest xml

Comment: @Kartheek please see the code

Comment: share your MainActivity Code.

Comment: Why did you specified android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED for the MainActivity.?

Comment: @Kartheek for update the media data base. If I delete any music it still show that music. That's why.

Comment: @Tushar can you share your MainActivity. The problem might be there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is   `<data android:scheme="file" />` , you cannot logically use this tag in launcher activity.

Set if the activity should be an option for the default action (center press) to perform on a piece of data. Setting this will hide from the user any activities without it set when performing an action on some data. Note that this is normal -not- set in the Intent when initiating an action — it is for use in intent filters specified in packages.

Comment: Can you please tell me another thing? Clicking the run button in the android studio it was launching the app automatically. But now it just install, dont launch the app. why so? is it also the reason of that tag?

Comment: May it could be the problem

Comment: saved my day . . .